# Handling multiple promises in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I have the following scenario to implement in node.

1. Printing random words inside a loop.
2. There is an asynchronous function to call for that **(printRandomWord)**.
3. The function has a delay of 0.5 seconds to get the response.
4. I have to call this function inside a loop from 1 to 20.
5. It takes 10 seconds to print 20 random words since the printRandomWord has a 0.5 s delay.

What I want to do is, print 20 random words in less than 1 second.

I was told that there is a way to do that, but I couldn't find the solution yet.

This is my code.

```
 const printWords = async () => {
   for (let x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {
     console.log(await printRandomWord());
   }
 };
```

Comment: You can use an array of Promises and call `Promise.all` on them, or if you really aren't doing anything else in the function and the order of logs doesn't matter, you can just do `printRandomWord().then(console.log).catch(handleError)` inside the loop

Comment: Or something along the lines of `Promise.all(Array.from({length: 100}, printRandomWord)).then(console.log);`. This prints all words at once.